# Location alerts using Core Data to get around CLRegion 20 region cap

Tags: core-data, ios8, cllocationmanager, geofencing

I have an app that stores points of interest (POIs) in a Core Data `managedObjectContext`. My objective is to have alerts go off if `currentLocation` is within a specified range of a POI in the `managedObjectContext`. In reading about `CLRegion`, it seems the amount of regions that can be monitored is capped at 20.

To get around the region monitoring cap, my game plan is to skim my `managedObjectContext` for latitude/longitude coordinates and compute  distances between POIs every time my location manager's `didUpdateLocations` fires in my app:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"LocationManager Latitude %+.6f, Longitude %+.6f\n",
          location.coordinate.latitude,
          location.coordinate.longitude);
    // TODO: compute distances between objects in managedObjectContext
    [self calculateDistances];
    self.currentLocation = location;
}

// method to compute distances
- (void) calculateDistances {

    // for POI in managedObjectContext, do the following
    CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:self.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:POIlatitude longitude:POIlongitude];

    CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];

    if (distance < 1000) {
        // popup alert
    }

}
```

I've only used `managedObjectContext` to display data. In this case, I'm not displaying anything--instead, I'm just running through the objects in my `MOC` when `didUpdateLocations` fires, pulling out coordinates and computing a distance. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you don't want to display the data, then don't execute any code that puts it on the screen. What part doesn't make sense?

Comment: I updated my post for added clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called my class `LocationManager` and it's a singleton class. In the header, I added a property for `NSManagedObjectContext`.

`.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

My Core Data stack is in my AppDelegate, so I tweaked the init method of my `LocationManager` implementation to "see" it:

`.m`

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self.locationManager) {
        // This is so I can get a reference to the managedObjectContext
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];

        if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
            [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        }

        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 100; // meters
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Further down, when the `didUpdateLocations` method fires, I added a call to `[self calculateDistances]`, like so:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"LocationManager Latitude %+.6f, Longitude %+.6f\n",
          location.coordinate.latitude,
          location.coordinate.longitude);
    [self calculateDistances];
    self.currentLocation = location;
}

// method to compute distances
- (void) calculateDistances {

    NSError *error;
    NSFetchRequest *coordinateRetrieval = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"PointOfInterest"];
    NSArray *pois = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:coordinateRetrieval error:&error];

    for (PointOfInterest *venue in poi) {
        CLLocation *locA = self.currentLocation;
        CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[venue.latitude doubleValue] longitude:[venue.longitude doubleValue]];
        CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];

        if (distance < 1000) {
            // popup alert
        }
        NSLog(@"The distance from currentLocation to venue is %lf meters", distance);
    }
}
```